# How can I use the result of this query as source of another query that extract n random records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem.

I am trying to implement a query that select some random record from a table.

I have found this interesting article: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

So I am following this example:

```
SELECT name
  FROM random AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT (RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM random)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 3;
```

It seems works fine.

Now my problem is that I am trying to adapt it to my situation.

I have not a simple single **random** table as source of my data but instead the **random** table I have to extract 3 random reocords from the entire set of the records returned by this query:

```
SELECT * FROM room_media rm1
JOIN room r ON rm1.id_room = r.id
JOIN room_tipology rt ON r.id_room_tipology_fk = rt.id
where rt.id = 1
```

How can I consider the result of this query as a table and use it instead the previous **random** table of the example? Doing in this way can I have some performance problem?

Comment: Your query does not return 3 random rows.  It returns 3 rows starting from a single random id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the first one?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Yes, your first query. That is explained directly under the example code in your link. If you scroll down, your link also provides solutions for multiple rows. Basically: execute the 1-row-query that best fits your setup (e.g. if you have holes/no holes in your ids) multiple times, until you get 3 different values. You can use and adjust that principle your exact requirements (procedure/function/programming language). It's hard (and requires special circumstances/requirements) to get much faster than this, since it will require just some (fast) index lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not get 3 *random* rows.  It gets three rows ordered by id starting from a single random id.  These are very different.

The simplest way to get "n" random records is to use `order by rand()` and `limit`.  So, start with this:

```
SELECT *  -- you should list column names explicitly
FROM room_media rm1 JOIN
     room r
     ON rm1.id_room = r.id JOIN
     room_tipology rt
     ON r.id_room_tipology_fk = rt.id
WHERE rt.id = 1 
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 3;
```

There are numerous other ways to get random rows; these are generally used when the above approach does not meet performance goals.

Comment: No, this works but could cause performance issue with many records. I want combine the output of the first query with the second one